# Privacy settings icon not visible in gnome 3.8

Tags: gnome, 13.04

In my settings menu of ubuntu-gnome, gnome 3.8.2, I do not have a icon for privacy settings. I however would like to access the privacy settings... How can I do this?

-- Edit --

I still would like an answer, and yes of course I searched for "privacy" in the search box ;-)

[image]

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/gnome-38-released-see-whats-new-video.html i am not sure but this link may help you go through once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 and ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging to get the privacy icons . 
Same happened to me i only installed the first ppa and when i reread the article it said you need to install both.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "System Settings" does Gnome3.8 not have a header that is just "Settings"?
I've read that privacy features are back in Gnome 3.8 and that you can find them under "Settings"

Comment: No sorry, this is the only settings page I have next to the tweaktool.