# Privacy and Search panels missing from System Settings in Gnome 3.8

Tags: gnome, 13.10, system-settings

Upgraded to Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 (Gnome 3.8).

I was expecting to see Privacy and Search panel in System Settings. But they are missing.

How do I get these? Do I need to install any additional packages?

Comment: I'm also looking for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 and ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging to get the privacy icons as stated in: [Privacy settings icon not visible in gnome 3.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300325/privacy-settings-icon-not-visible-in-gnome-3-8)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Then just upgrade your gnome.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Hope that helps.