# How to adjust the search path for gnome-photos app?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, photo-management, photo, gnome-shell

I'm wondering whether it is possible to adjust the search paths (and make the **search recursive**) of the default photo app (gnome-photos). I could not find any settings for this.

Why? It finds photos from my Download folder, but not from my **photo subfolders hierarchy**, which means it is full of nothing that is important to me. I'd like to exclude the downloads folder and include all or at least some of my subfolders (`~/Photos/darktable/**`).

I'm using Ubuntu-Gnome 17.04 with all Updates etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search paths of Photos (and other apps) are stored in Settings->Search where you can also modify them.

Maybe you can't see the Search icon in Settings because [Privacy and Search panels missing from System Settings in Gnome 3.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362241/privacy-and-search-panels-missing-from-system-settings-in-gnome-3-8)

Please inform us if that is your case

Comment: I can see those settings, but I think I did not emphasize my problem well. The thing is that I have so many subfolders, and I often creates new ones. I'd like to have it to search my directory recursively, like with `~/Photos/**`. (I'll edit the question to emphasize this.). But I can't see a way to express this in the settings. (Before I thought the Photos folder is not searched, but I just now realized it just does not recursively.)

Comment: I  did guess that kind of search was the default!

Comment: I switched all paths on and off again (I also tried adding the paths manually and deleted them again), and it seems to work now. Thank you :)